# Mysql: Wrong return with Order By

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I want To achieve last time when client was last visited me.

```
auto Table Structure:  
---id_auto
---client_id

auto_problems Table Structure
--id_auto
--add_date
```

With query

```
"SELECT add_date
FROM auto_problems
LEFT JOIN auto ON auto_problems.id_auto = auto.id_auto
WHERE client_id = 466
ORDER BY `auto_problems`.`add_date` ASC"
```

**Query return:**

```
01/07/2014
04/03/2014 **<<<---- ???**
11/04/2014
16/09/2014
```

Why ODER BY add_date ASC Dont work?

Comment: and the dates are stored as varchar ?

Comment: Do not store the dates as varchar!

Comment: so why ASC if you need the latest one? should be `ORDER BY \`auto_problems\`.\`add_date\` DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: where is your source data? that is absolutely unclear why `04/03/2014` is the latest visit of client=466

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your string representing the date to a date:

```
SELECT add_date
FROM auto_problems
LEFT JOIN auto ON auto_problems.id_auto = auto.id_auto
WHERE client_id = 466
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`auto_problems`.`add_date`,'%d/%m/%Y') ASC
```

But you should Change your data type to `date`. It is a better practice.

Comment: Thanks. It works ;) I don`t have permision to change table structure @DB.